Vibration frequency estimation at pixel level using Event Driven Camera dataset (prophesee)
I'm working on calculating the vibration frequency at each pixel. Using the example dataset (vibration estimation) available in prophesee's website. Can anyone help me with the approach to be used to determine the frequency. link to the dataset
I tried fft with scipy, but dont know a way to validate them.
